# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes!

Tags: nvidia, gpu-driver

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit on my PC. After I've installed nVidia drivers (recommended) to solve the problem of the cursor that vanishes, Ubuntu freezes randomly when I'm working, I mean that the system doesn't react to my actions except when I press Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then Ctrl+Alt+F7, with this solution everything returns to normal. I've narrowed down the cause to these 3:

- The drivers don't work correctly
- I was wrong to install Ubuntu on an ext4 partition
- The swap partition is too relevant to the RAM (when I write in terminal `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` it reports a value of 60).

I don't want to install another distro before I've tried everything possible!

Asus X53S Series, nVidia GeForce 610M 2GB dedicated, Intel Core i7 (2,20 GHz) 64bit, RAM 4GB.

Comment: Note that catting /proc/sys/vm/swappiness shows you a Kernel setting, not some statistics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness - so having a value of 60 means nothing except that the value has not been changed away from its default.

Comment: Also, did you check the kernel log after the problem occurred. Type "dmesg" into a terminal for that.

Comment: Finally, related with some solutions is the following post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/464534/ubuntu-14-04-lts-randomly-freezes-graphics-unity-only?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an nvidia Optimus (hybrid graphics) setup. You need to remove the nvidia driver and use bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current
```

To install bumblebee in Ubuntu 14.04, run these commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-331
```

Now you have to install Bumblebee GUI to manage apps to be opened using nVidia. Here is the instructions:

Install Python App Indicator:

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

Install Git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Make a directory for git:

```
mkdir git && cd git
```

Check out the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bumblebee-ui.git
cd bumblebee-ui
sudo ./INSTALL
```

Go to Startup Applications and add bumblebee-indicator

Now reboot.

[I did not write this here is the source for the you need optimus info](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1947706)

[This one is the install instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04)

Comment: Thenks a lot! It works! I'm so happy! :)